# Binding issues for embedded layout in axml MVVMCROSS

Tags: c#, android-layout, xamarin, mvvmcross

I have a layout which is kinda footer view which is included in almost all the layout .

Suppose we take example of a textview which is not directly present in activity layout rather its in different layout which is included in layout .

example case :

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:gravity="bottom|center">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_awesome_intro"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/dp_awesome_intro"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/dp_awesome_intro_margin_bottom"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_welcome_intro" />
    <include
        layout="@layout/BarButton"
        android:id="@+id/btn_welcome_join"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/dp_awesome_learnmore_size" />
    <include
        layout="@layout/BarButton"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/btn_welcome_learnmore"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/dp_awesome_learnmore_size" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Included BarButton layout is as follows :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:background="#229DCF"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingLeft="15dp"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/dp_button_margin_right"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:textSize="@dimen/sp_button_title"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:id="@+id/titleLbl" />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iconImg"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/dp_button_imgsize"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/dp_button_imgsize"
        android:layout_marginTop="5px"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dp_button_margin_betweentxt"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_forward_arrow" />
</LinearLayout>
```

My question is how I can bind Textview click event to viewmodel's command
This textview is present inside a BarButton layout not directly in activity layout .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can still bind to the `TextView`. The include is just a pattern provided by [Android's layout system](https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html) to create re-usable layouts. When the layout tree is created it will add the elements defined in the include into the existing layout.

> To efficiently re-use complete layouts, you can use the `<include/>` and
>   `<merge/>` tags **to embed another layout inside the current layout**.

You can then use either XML or Fluent binding for your command.

[XML binging](https://www.mvvmcross.com/documentation/fundamentals/data-binding#swiss)

```
<TextView
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:textSize="@dimen/sp_button_title"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
    android:id="@+id/titleLbl"
    app:MvxBind="Click MyCommand"/>
```

[Fluent binding](https://www.mvvmcross.com/documentation/fundamentals/data-binding#fluent)

```
var title = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.titleLbl);

...

bindingSet.Bind(title)
    .For(c => c.BindClick())
    .To(vm => vm.MyCommand)
    .Apply();
```

If you want to reduce the duplication of this command between `ViewModel` (Pages/layouts) you can share the `ViewModel` command in a base class.

Comment: I would make myself clear again , I know I can go to element and bind it the way u mentioned above .

crux of the matter is that textview is inside a layout which is reused many places , so by binding that way I won't be generic .

Like they way you have above ,"MyCommand" would be present in all the view model for all the layout attached to activities .

Comment: @saketkumar, the `BindClick()` requires that you add a using `MvvmCross.Binding.Droid`, see [docs](https://www.mvvmcross.com/documentation/fundamentals/data-binding#built-in-bindings) for complete list.

Comment: You can add the command in to a base class ViewModel and then have all ViewModel for the pages that require it inherit the base ViewModel. That way there is only one copy of the command. That way it is only present if you want inherit it.

Comment: Solved the problem Thanks !